# Continue building React project with newer version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture, create-react-app, micro-frontend

I have a really big project with React version 16.6.0 with Class components...
I would like to upgrade the project to a newer version of react (18 for example), but the code base is so large, just can't change it all. So I thought of something like creating a new react app, but how can I connect these 2 together, I need some advice.

Comment: What advantages in functionality are you hoping to get by upgrading?

Comment: `but the code base is so large, just can't change it all.`  Why would you need to change it all?,  from what I can gather class components have not gone, there are changes in bootstrapping your root component, and lifecycles methods have maybe changed from 16 to 18, but I would expect most React 16 components should work in 18, main area that might need tweaking are render lifecycle methods, but basic components should transfer as is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Mainly my purpose to update to react 18 is to totally use functional components along the whole project. So if I simply upgrade it to React 18 will it continue working as before? and from that point I'll start building with functional components and I also want to continue writing it with typescript, that's why I thought of something like creating a new app from scratch and somehow connect it with older one.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar situation when I had to add features to an old react app.

Fundamentally React, by design, is incrementally useable, i.e., you can use React only in certain parts of the app and the rest can be anything. Similarly, you could use Hooks & Functional Components in a incremental way.

Start by using Functional Components & Hooks only for the new features that you add. Later if you want to make changes to existing features try to rewrite them with FC one by one.

You **DO NOT** have to start with a new react app from the scratch.

Comment: Does React 16 support functional components?

Comment: @SisNikoyan Hooks were introduced in React 16.8

Answer (score 0):

### Without a new app

1. Upgrade to react 16 latest version.

React `16.x` versions greater than 16.8, such as `16.14.0`, would be a good choice for you. No major breaking changes, and with react hooks(advanced functional components) support.

2. Using multiple react versions.

Checkout

- https://medium.jonasbandi.net/hosting-multiple-react-applications-on-the-same-document-c887df1a1fcd
- https://betterprogramming.pub/6-steps-to-create-a-multi-version-react-application-1c3e5b5df7e9

### With a new app

3. Mix two react apps with an Nginx server.

Place all your new pages inside a subroute, such as `https://my_domain/new/*`, then configure your nginx server:

```
{
    location / {
        root /old-html;
    }

    location /new/ {
        root /new-html;
    }
}
```

You need to handle authorization in the new react app, though.